# How do I sum only the 3 best scores from this query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I need to sum only the 5 best scores for each player from 11 events. The query below creates a leaderboard which sums all the scores but I'm stuck as to how i can only sum the 5 best scores.

I've abbreviated the query to show only 4 events and getting best 3 results to shorten the post, but hope it gets across, what I need.

```
SELECT playerID AS Player,
  SUM(CASE WHEN championshipleaderboard.eventID = 1 THEN championshipleaderboard.points ELSE 0 END) AS Event1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN championshipleaderboard.eventID = 2 THEN championshipleaderboard.points ELSE 0 END) AS Event2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN championshipleaderboard.eventID = 3 THEN championshipleaderboard.points ELSE 0 END) AS Event3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN championshipleaderboard.eventID = 4 THEN championshipleaderboard.points ELSE 0 END) AS Event4,
  SUM(championshipleaderboard.points) AS Total 
FROM (
  championshipleaderboard JOIN members ON championshipleaderboard.playerId = members.playerId
)
GROUP BY championshipleaderboard.playerId
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

table: championshipLeaderboard

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| Player | EventID | Points |
+--------+---------+--------+
|      1 |       1 |     25 |
|      2 |       1 |     20 |
|      1 |       2 |     15 |
|      2 |       2 |     13 |
|      1 |       3 |     20 |
|      2 |       3 |     12 |
|      1 |       4 |     20 |
|      2 |       4 |     10 |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

Current Result is

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Player | Event1 | Event2 | Event3 | Event4 | Total |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|      1 |     25 |     15 |     20 |     20 |    80 |
|      2 |     20 |     13 |     12 |     10 |    55 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Result Needed is

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
| Player | Event1 | Event2 | Event3 | Event4 | Total(best3) |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
|      1 |     25 |     15 |     20 |     20 |           65 |
|      2 |     20 |     13 |     12 |     10 |           45 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to that each player-event pair is unique? Can it contain duplicates e.g. `1, 1, 10` and `1, 1, 20`?

Comment: each player event pair is unique, I do have an auto-incrementing ID column, but didnt put it in the question, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way - although in MySQL 8+, you'd use more contemporary techniques...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(Player INT NOT NULL
,EventID INT NOT NULL
,Points INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(player,eventid)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,25),
(2,1,20),
(1,2,15),
(2,2,13),
(1,3,20),
(2,3,12),
(1,4,20),
(2,4,10);

SELECT player
     , SUM(points) top3 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = player THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=player 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars ORDER BY player,points
DESC) a 
        WHERE i<=3 
        GROUP 
           BY player;
+--------+------+
| player | top3 |
+--------+------+
|      1 |   65 |
|      2 |   45 |
+--------+------+
```

Comment: This works well, how would I get a ranking column preceding the player column using above query?

Comment: You would normally handle that kind of thing in application code - same with the 'Event1','Event2' stuff

Comment: Thanks for the advice, thats my next mission sorted then!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated sub-query to find the 3rd best score, and sum the scores equal to/greater than the 3rd best score:

```
SELECT Player
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Eventid = 1 THEN points END) AS Event1
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Eventid = 2 THEN points END) AS Event2
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Eventid = 3 THEN points END) AS Event3
     , MIN(CASE WHEN Eventid = 4 THEN points END) AS Event4
     , SUM(CASE WHEN (Points, ID) >= (
        SELECT Points, ID
        FROM t AS x
        WHERE x.Player = t.Player
        ORDER BY Points DESC, ID DESC
        LIMIT 2, 1
     ) THEN Points END) AS TopThree
FROM t
GROUP BY Player
```

Notice that ties between sorted points are broken by ordering by `Points DESC, ID DESC`; thus if a player's scores are `(1, 20), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 30)` then `(4, 30), (3, 30), (2, 20)` are summed.

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6bce558f2226a56a3f7e5e7db71132ae)

Comment: I get `Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)` when running this query and detected that the select in sub-query missing `ID` column > `SELECT Points, ID`. Otherwise I think this works great!

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes it was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/332F6XA3J3GaxXeD7LFP81/0

Live test:

```sql
with ranking as
(
    select
        player,       
        rank() over(partition by player order by points desc) as xrank,
        points
    from tbl
)
select
    player, 
    sum(if(eventid = 1, points, 0)) as event1,
    sum(if(eventid = 2, points, 0)) as event2,
    sum(if(eventid = 3, points, 0)) as event3,  
    sum(if(eventid = 4, points, 0)) as event4,
    sum(
        if(
            (player,points) in
                (select player,points 
                from ranking 
                where xrank <= 3), 
            points, 
            0 
        ) 
    ) as best3
from tbl
group by player
```

Output:

```
| player | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | best3 |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 25     | 15     | 20     | 20     | 65    |
| 2      | 20     | 13     | 12     | 10     | 45    |
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a subquery, within a query grouped by concat(player ID, event ID), with a limit of 3 (or 5, or however many).

Tested this on similar tables within my own DB and worked.

Edited SQL:

```
SELECT cl.eventID, m.playerID,
   (SELECT 
        SUM(cl2.points)
    FROM
        championshipleaderboard cl2
    WHERE
        cl2.playerID = pr.playerID
            AND cl2.eventID = cl.eventID
    ORDER BY cl2.points DESC
    LIMIT 3) AS top_x_sum
 FROM championshipleaderboard cl, members m
   WHERE cl.playerID = m.playerID

 GROUP BY CONCAT(cl.eventID, m.playerID);
```

Comment: Missing `GROUP BY` function. Getting error `Error Code: 1140
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Yeah, was barking up the wrong tree here, limit is not applying in the way desired.

Comment: Revised SQL, after playing about with it in my own database with similar tables (product review scores, in my case, grouping by customer and product ID).

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank`

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ufuFAXKf7mi5yefNQqoXM/2

```
with ranking as
(
   select 
      player,       
      rank() over(partition by player order by points desc) as xrank,
      points
  from tbl
)
,pick3 as
(
  select player, sum(points) as best3
  from ranking 
  where xrank <= 3
  group by player
)
select
   t.player, 
   sum(if(t.eventid = 1, t.points,0)) as event1,
   sum(if(t.eventid = 2, t.points,0)) as event2,
   sum(if(t.eventid = 3, t.points,0)) as event3,  
   sum(if(t.eventid = 4, t.points,0)) as event4,
   p.best3            
from tbl t
join pick3 p on t.player = p.player
group by t.player
```

Output:

```
| player | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | best3 |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 25     | 15     | 20     | 20     | 65    |
| 2      | 20     | 13     | 12     | 10     | 45    |
```

Comment: I guess this only works with MySql 8.0? As I get an error when running in 5.7.23. Is there an alternative as it does the job perfectly!

Comment: I'm still coming up with clearer solution that would work on MySQL 5.x (pre-windowing-function, e.g., `rank`). MySQL don't even support the combo of `LIMIT` + `IN/ALL/ANY/SOME`  http://www.anicehumble.com/2019/04/mysql-doesnt-support-limit-in-all-any-some.html. If it did, it would work on MySQL 5.x (pre-windowing-function)

Comment: MySQL 5.7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898696/how-do-i-sum-only-the-3-best-scores-from-this-query/55900191#55900191

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ufuFAXKf7mi5yefNQqoXM/15

```
select
    t.player, 
    sum(case when t.eventid = 1 then t.points end) as event1,
    sum(case when t.eventid = 2 then t.points end) as event2,
    sum(case when t.eventid = 3 then t.points end) as event3,
    sum(case when t.eventid = 4 then t.points end) as event4,

    sum(
        case when t.points >= (
            select best3.points 
            from tbl best3 
            where best3.player = t.player
            order by best3.points desc 
            limit 1 offset 2 -- offset starts with 0. so 2 is the third
        ) then 
            t.points
        end
    ) as best3            
from tbl t
group by t.player;
```

Output:

```
| player | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | best3 |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 25     | 15     | 20     | 20     | 65    |
| 2      | 20     | 13     | 12     | 10     | 45    |
```

Comment: Hi, been a while since original question, but we've just got to stage in season where we have played 6 events. Your answer has worked well until now but somethings gone awry. Only 2 golfers have played all 6 events but the formula is summing all 6 scores and not just best 5
This fiddle 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ufuFAXKf7mi5yefNQqoXM/19
shows the exact scores, any idea, is it because both players have 2 scores which are the same?