# Why does this SUM all scores and not just best 5 score?

Tags: mysql

This follows on from this question

[How do I sum only the 3 best scores from this query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898696/how-do-i-sum-only-the-3-best-scores-from-this-query)

We have now got to stage in season where some players have played in 6 events, now the code I used from above question is supposed to sum only the 5 best scores but from this fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ufuFAXKf7mi5yefNQqoXM/19

is adding all 6 scores not just top 5.

I would like the desired result to look like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| player | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | event5 | event6 | best5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1      | 15     | 8      | 15     | 9      | 8      | 14     | 61    |
| 2      | 5      | 9      | 5      | 12     | 9      | 15     | 50    | 
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Where have i gone wrong

Comment: Hint: `OFFSET` counts from 0, not 1. And you also have ties in scores so even if you fix the offset the tied values (e.g. 8, 8 for player 1) will be summed twice.

Comment: Why not accept an answer to the previous question first

Comment: @strawberry sorry missed that, done

Comment: @SalmanA offset 4 for 5th score or am I missing something

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: As in the fiddle above but with final column totalling only 5 best scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
select
t.player, 
sum(case when t.eventid = 1 then t.points end) as event1,
sum(case when t.eventid = 2 then t.points end) as event2,
sum(case when t.eventid = 3 then t.points end) as event3,
sum(case when t.eventid = 4 then t.points end) as event4,
sum(case when t.eventid = 5 then t.points end) as event5,
sum(case when t.eventid = 6 then t.points end) as event6,  
t2.best5
from tbl t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT player, sum(points) as best5 FROM (SELECT points, player, IF(@lastPlayer=(@lastPlayer:=player), @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=1) indx  
    FROM tbl, (SELECT @lastPlayer := 0, @auto := 1) A ORDER BY player, points desc) as a
    WHERE indx <= 5
    GROUP BY player
) t2 
ON t.player = t2.player
group by t.player;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9vtg8fZLpb4v2ytKahmwhA/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   Player INTEGER,
   EventId INTEGER,
   Points INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY(player,eventid)
 );


 INSERT INTO tbl
   (Player, EventID, Points)
 VALUES
   (1, 1, 15),
   (2, 1, 5),
   (1, 2, 8),
   (2, 2, 9),
   (1, 3, 15),
   (2, 3, 5),
   (1, 4, 9),
   (2, 4, 12),
   (1, 5, 8),
   (2, 5, 9),
   (1, 6, 14),
   (2, 6, 15);

-- Exclusively for versions of MySQL prior to 8.0 --

SELECT player
     , SUM(CASE WHEN i <=3 THEN points END) best3 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN i <=5 THEN points END) best5 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = player THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=player prev
         FROM tbl x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY player
            , points DESC
     ) n 
 GROUP 
    BY player;
+--------+-------+-------+
| player | best3 | best5 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 |    44 |    61 |
|      2 |    36 |    50 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks @strawberry that’s an answer on previous question but I would like it to display as in fiddle above. It needs to show all event scores with the final column showing total of 5 best scores

Comment: @Jon I consider that a task for application level code; so I'll leave it to others to provide a SQL version.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice will look into that option